# Build Error : amplify cannot find module @absolutepath

Tags: typescript, aws-amplify

I'm a junior frontend engineer.

I wanna ask something about amplify.

I used absolute path in my app service because I have to seperate my service with domain.
before my code was like '../../../../......' too long and I couldn't understand path. so, i have to change absolute path with craco package.

it was operated absoultely in my local env. but when I use Amplify it has a problem like this.

```
./src/App.tsx
 Cannot find module: '@lms/my/directory'. Make sure this package is installed.
You can install this package by running: yarn add '@common/my/directory'
2022-04-04T09:32:11.221Z [WARNING]: error Command failed with exit code 1.
2022-04-04T09:32:11.223Z [INFO]: info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
2022-04-04T09:32:11.227Z [ERROR]: !!! Build failed
2022-04-04T09:32:11.228Z [ERROR]: !!! Non-Zero Exit Code detected
2022-04-04T09:32:11.228Z [INFO]: # Starting environment caching...
2022-04-04T09:32:11.229Z [INFO]: # Uploading environment cache artifact...
2022-04-04T09:32:11.294Z [INFO]: # Environment caching completed
```

and I seached this message, I found solution about 'tsconfig.json', 'craco.config.js'.. but they weren't operate.

It is my 'tsconfig.json' and 'craco.config.js'

```
//tsconfig.json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.paths.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src",
    "styles"
  ]
}

//tsconfig.paths.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@common/*": ["src/domain/common/*"],
      "@lms/*": ["src/domain/lms/*"],
      "@membership/*": ["src/domain/membership/*"],
      "@outcomes/*": ["src/domain/outcomes-jobs/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

```
//craco.config.js
const CracoAlias = require('craco-alias');

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      plugin: CracoAlias,
      options: {
        source: 'tsconfig',
        tsConfigPath: 'tsconfig.paths.json'
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

and my directory structure.

```
src
  ㄴdomain
      ㄴlms
      ㄴcommon
      ㄴmembership
      ㄴoutcomes
```

how can I use Amplify..? oh! it's my amplify setting.

```
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - yarn install
    build:
      commands:
        - yarn build
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: build
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

if I got a wrong way, please tell me.
thank you!